# Simple Text in OpenGL (without GLUT)

Tags: opengl, text

I am making a simple 2D platformer with **C++, SDL and OpenGL** and now I would like to *display text* on the screen, e.g. points, timer, simple messages.

On various site's I've read that Bitmap Fonts would probably be the way to go for this, but could someone please give me a straightforward, easy to understand example of how to use them in OpenGL to output a test-message to the screen?

**EDIT:** I found something interesting, **FTGL**. The example-code in the tutorial (2nd link) looks very straightforward. Couldn't get it to work atm but will go back to it later.

*FTGL is a free cross-platform Open Source C++ library that uses Freetype2 to simplify rendering fonts in OpenGL applications. FTGL supports bitmaps, pixmaps, texture maps, outlines, polygon mesh, and extruded polygon rendering modes.*

1. http://sourceforge.net/projects/ftgl/
2. http://ftgl.sourceforge.net/docs/html/ftgl-tutorial.html
3. http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/freetype_fonts_in_opengl/24001/

Answer (score 2):

You can use [SDL_gfx](http://www.ferzkopp.net/joomla/content/view/19/14/), it can output text using bitmap fonts like this:

```
#include <SDL/SDL_gfxPrimitives.h>
#include <SDL/SDL_gfxPrimitives_font.h>

const char *text = "text to render";
stringColor(sdlSurface, x, y, text, 0xff0000ff);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a bitmap image, containing all the characters you want to use. The easiest way is with a fixed-width font. Then for each letter you bind that part of the texture. I've written such code in Pascal/OpenGL years ago, will search for it and post

Edit here is the code

```
procedure DisplayString(str: string; l: integer; active: integer; align: integer);
var i,n: integer;
s: string;
begin
  glPushMatrix;
  glTranslatef(0,-l,0);
  if align=1 then glTranslatef(-15,0,0); //left alignment
  if align=3 then glTranslatef(15,0,0);//right aligment
  s:=uppercase(str); // the font is uppercase only
  for i:=1 to length(str)-4 do begin
   n:=ord(s[i]); // get the ASCII code of letter
   glTranslatef(1,0,0);
   if n=32 then continue; //space
   if (n>=48) and (n<=58) then n:=n-47; // translate ascii code to the
   if (n>=65) and (n<=90) then n:=n-53; // corresponding position in the bitmap
      if active=0 then glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, font2) // two different font files used
    else glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, font);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS); // 1850 is the total width of the bitmap image, 50 is one character
     glTexCoord2f(((n-1)*50/1850)-1, 0.0); glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0,  1.0);
     glTexCoord2f((n*50/1850)-1, 0.0); glVertex3f(1.0, 0.0,  1.0);
     glTexCoord2f((n*50/1850)-1, 1.0); glVertex3f(1.0, 1.0,  1.0);
     glTexCoord2f(((n-1)*50/1850)-1, 1.0); glVertex3f(0.0, 1.0,  1.0);
    glEnd();
    end;
   glPopMatrix;
end;
```

Comment: Not quite sure that this is what I'm talking about. Why can't I just use some available font, such as arial, verdana etc?

Comment: Because OpenGL can't render them. You can use additioanl libraries for that. Check out this FAQ: http://www.opengl.org/resources/faq/technical/fonts.htm

Answer (score 1):

When you use SDL already why not add [SDL_ttf](http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/docs/index.html)?

> SDL_ttf is a TrueType font rendering library that is used with the SDL
>   library, and almost as portable. It depends on freetype2 to handle the
>   TrueType font data. It allows a programmer to use multiple TrueType
>   fonts without having to code a font rendering routine themselves. With
>   the power of outline fonts and antialiasing, high quality text output
>   can be obtained without much effort.

Answer (score -2):

I used bitmap fonts that are available in GLUT. The respective calls in JOGL (Java + OpenGL) are:

```
GLU glu = new GLU();
GLUT glut = new GLUT();
GL gl = drawable.getGL();
gl.glRasterPos3f(x, y, z); // move to (x, y, z) for the next text output
glut.glutBitmapString(GLUT.BITMAP_HELVETICA_12, "Message");
gl.glRasterPos3f (x2, y2, z2);
glut.glutBitmapCharacter (GLUT.BITMAP_HELVETICA_18, 'X');
```

This can surely be adapted to OpenGL + C++ easily.